# Local Storage Update Cart Total

Tags: local-storage, cart, shopping-cart, subtotal

I am looking to store just the cart subtotal in my local storage. I am using GTM to call the add to cart event and get the price that has been added to the cart. From there I want to just update that price or create a cart value that updates each time another item is added. Once I get the add function figured out I can easily fill in the gaps when something is removed or a qty is updated.

```
// this is the GTM call to track what the price is when the add to cart button is pushed
var pr = {{DL - Add To Cart}};

// Store product price in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('price', pr.price);
```

The above I have no problem with. I get the price to show each time an item is added. Below is the code I am working with to update the price as each additional price is added. The main issue I am trying to work around is I have over complicated the cart to show in {[]} and I want it instead to display just as the above code ('price', pr.price) is showing so a simple number.

```
var addItem = function (price) {
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartvalue')) || [] ;
    var match = oldItems.find(function (item) {
        return item['price'] = price;
    });
    if (match) {
        match['price'] += price;
    } else {
        var newItem = {
            'price': price,
        };
        oldItems.push(newItem);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('cartvalue', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
};

 addItem(pr.price);
```

Comment: Clarify: "The main issue I am trying to work around is I have over complicated the cart to show in {[]} and I want it instead to display just as the above code ('price', pr.price) is showing so a simple number."

Comment: @Devashish when I was having the issue my local storage would show:
Key: cartvalue
Value: {["price":24.99]}

instead I was looking for
Key: cartvalue
Value: 24.99

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was finally able to make work. This now shows only the value of the cart in a numeric value instead of {["price": xx.xx]}

```
<script>
 var pr = {{DL - Add To Cart}};

localStorage.setItem('price', pr.price);
localStorage.setItem('qty', pr.quantity); 

var addItem = function (price, qty) {
    var currentTotal = localStorage.getItem('cartvalue');
    if(currentTotal)
        currentTotal = parseFloat(currentTotal) + (parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty));
    else
        currentTotal = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty);
    localStorage.setItem('cartvalue', currentTotal);
};

 addItem(pr.price, pr.quantity);

</script>
```